# Unused label for data property in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I create a data property modalActive and then also created a method to toggle its value, now I am using it in my template in a v-if statement but I still get "unused label". I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

````
 
 <base-modal v-if = "modalActive">
 <template v-slot:heading> <h1><strong> This is the heading</strong></h1></template>
 <template v-slot:content>  <p>This is the content of the heading</p></template>
 </base-modal>
</header>


</template>


<script>
/*eslint-disable*/
import BaseModal from './BaseModal.vue';

export default {

components: {BaseModal},

data () {

 modalActive : false 
},

methods: {

toggleModal () {

 this.modalActive = !this.modalActive;
},
}

} 



</script> ```


**Could anyone tell what is the error that i am doing here.**
````

Comment: You need to share your BaseModal.vue, maybe a props on label is required.

Comment: Hey hi, I actually figured it out, in my script tag I was not returning anything. However, thanks for taking out time to answer :)